# What is the problem in this simple js code?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am wondering what`s the problem with this simple code. I am making a function where I need to get the length of the shortest word in a string. I know that I can find this function anywhere but,

why mine isn't working?

```
function findShort(s){
    var arr = s.split(" ");
    var out = 1000;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
          if (arr[i] <= out){
              out = arr[i].length;
          }
    }
    return out;
}
```

The above function returns 1000 instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compare the length of each word (`arr[i].length`), not each word itself (`arr[i]`) to the shortest length so far.

```
function findShort(s){
    var arr = s.split(" ");
    var out = 1000;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
          if (arr[i].length <= out){ // <-- here!
              out = arr[i].length;
          }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you compare strings in javascript, it doesn't use it's length. You have to use the "length" attribute of a String, like in the fixed code below. Also you have to save the result to give an output

```
function findShort(s){
    var arr = s.split(" ");
    var comp = 1000;
    var out = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
          if (arr[i].length <= comp){
              comp = arr[i].length;
              out = arr[i];
          }
    }
    return out;
}
```

There still is a problem, if you want to have an array returned with all the shortest words (same length). You could add another if statement and make it add the word to an array when it's the same length, and clear it when there was found a shorter one.

Comment: Understand. Thank you.